# Python Kernel timestamp UDP packet in windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, network-programming

is there a way to get the kernel timestamp of a UDP packet through python in windows? My understanding is that windows does allow access to the the timestamp of when the UDP packet arrived.

Answer (score 1):

You can use windows ETW (Event Tracing for Windows) to do that.
https://github.com/fireeye/pywintrace.

this are your provider infos:

```
"Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Network",
GUID("{7dd42a49-5329-4832-8dfd-43d979153a88}")
```